# Fails to run polkadot on macbook m1 chip with error: <jemalloc>: Error allocating TSD

Tags: polkadot, rust, macos

The polkadot project builds with no problems on my m1 chip macbook, but when I try to execute the executatble, I get the following error

```
❯ ./target/release/polkadot --chain=polkadot

<jemalloc>: Error allocating TSD
[1]    87791 abort      ./target/release/polkadot --chain=polkadot
```

How do I workaround this?

Comment: Looks like that error comes from somewhere around https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jemalloc_new/+/aa77b3afdde56db228afb40a9b897bae4f17ebe4/include/jemalloc/internal/tsd_generic.h#104 TSD . stands for thread specific data.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve the original problem, but a workaround was to change the allocator in parity-util-mem dependency of the Cargo.toml before compiling polkadot.

I changed it from `jemalloc-global` to `mimalloc-global`

ie

```
parity-util-mem = { version = "0.11.0", default-features = false, features = ["jemalloc-global"] }
```

to

```
parity-util-mem = { version = "0.11.0", default-features = false, features = ["mimalloc-global"] }
```